# Passing authenticated session from selenium to scrapy

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I am trying to login in a website using selenium then pass the authenticated session to scrapy to extract stuff.

The issue is that after I pass the session to scrapy I am still not logged in.

```
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'login'
allowed_domains = ['*****']

start_urls = ['*****']
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
def start_requests(self):
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get('*****')
    time.sleep(5)
    portalButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fb_submit"]')
    portalButton.click()
    time.sleep(2)


    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys('******')
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('******')
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-login"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies():
        c = {cookie['name']: cookie['value']}
    yield Request(url="****",cookies=c,callback=self.parse)




def parse(self,response):
    # self.log("->>>>>>>>>>>>")
    open_in_browser(response)
    # view(response)
    self.log("->>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest changing that step a bit:

```
for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies():
        c = {cookie['name']: cookie['value']}
```

to something like that:

```
_cookies = {cookie['name']: cookie['value'] for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies()}
yield Request(url="****",cookies=_cookies,callback=self.parse)
```

in each iteration you re-create **c** with **new** {cookie['name']: cookie['value']}

my code examples:

```
import time

import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'login'

    start_urls = ['URL']

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver.get('URL')
        time.sleep(5)

        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, ('email')).send_keys('EMAIL')
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, ('passwd')).send_keys('PASSWORD')
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, ('SubmitLogin')).click()
        _cookies = {cookie['name']: cookie['value'] for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies()}
        yield Request(url='URL',
                      cookies=_cookies,
                      callback=self.parse)
        self.driver.quit()

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        open_in_browser(response)
        self.log(response)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately it still did not work, when it reach op_in_browser I am still not logged in.

Comment: @Shaa'banMego just, checked locally, seems like works fine. first of all should you add super() to __init__?second, shouldn't be **kwargs to parse?by parent signature?

Comment: the page will load when it reach open_in_browser inside parse function but it I am not logged in it. I need to path the session in it

Comment: @Shaa'banMego what is the open_in_browser method?

Comment: it is basically a method that open the response in browser.

Comment: @Shaa'banMego I edited code, try to check it out again, from my side all works great, browser with logged in session opened successfully